# C graphics program generating static output

Tags: c, bgi, turbo-c

I have written a simple code to rotate a line. Following is the source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<graphics.h>
  void main(){
  int gd=DETECT, gm;
  int x1, y1, x2, y2, t, deg, b1, b2;
  initgraph(&gd,&gm,"c:\\tc\\bgi");
  printf("Enter coordinates of line: ");
  scanf("%d %d %d %d",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
  printf("Enter angle of rotation: ");
  scanf("%d",&deg);
  line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  getch();
  t = (22*deg)/(180*7);
  b1 = cos(t)*x1 - sin(t)*y1;
  b2 = cos(t)*x1 + sin(t)*y1;
  line(x1,y1,b1,b2);
  getch();
  closegraph();
}
```

The issue is that it generates a somewhat static output and does not rotate the line according to the input given. The rotated line is almost similar for any value deg variable.

Output:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Use float numbers. If you had a half-decent compiler you would have gotten numerous warnings about implicit integer to float conversions. You shouldn't learn C programming through non-standard, ancient junk compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `t` is an `int`, but the trigonometric functions require `float`s or `double`s.

So if you declare:

```
int x1, y1, x2, y2, deg, b1, b2;
float t;
```

It should work.
There may be more issues in your program.

BTW: give some obvious names to your variables, e.g. `angle` instead of `t.`

Also your conversion from degrees to radian is a bit clumsy as 22/7 is a rather crude approximation of PI:

```
t = (22*deg)/(180*7);
```

use rather this:

```
t = 3.1415926 * deg / 180
```

or even just this (if PI is declared in your math.h include file)

```
t = PI * deg / 180
```

Comment: I made the above changes still no help!

Comment: It should work. Debug your program by inserting some printfs to see what values you get in your variables (eg, `printf("x1 = %d, x2 = %d\n", x1, x2);`).

Comment: I tried the above, it gives out a static value of b1 as 3702 and b2 as 3208